# Pass nonconsecutive values as arguments to bash / awk script

Tags: bash, awk, arguments, range, option-type

Link to input file for testing is [samples.bin](https://usreliance.com/samples.bin)
I can pass ranges of values by delimiting two integers with a `-` in my script:

```
[root@usreliance Biorad]# ./sample12.sh -s 0-9 -c 0-3
                Ch0     Ch1     Ch2     Ch3
Sample 0:       0x1a03  0x1a03  0x4a03  0x5703
Sample 1:       0x4b03  0x4403  0x1e03  0x0904
Sample 2:       0x1003  0x1903  0x4003  0xae03
Sample 3:       0x1e03  0x2603  0x3303  0xad03
Sample 4:       0x1003  0x8403  0x4303  0x6203
Sample 5:       0xe003  0x1603  0x3403  0xc403
Sample 6:       0xf802  0x3b03  0x5303  0x6103
Sample 7:       0x1003  0x1503  0x4203  0x5803
Sample 8:       0x2303  0x1f03  0x5703  0x6203
Sample 9:       0x1703  0x7303  0x3103  0x3303

[root@usreliance Biorad]# ./sample12.sh -s 0-9 -c 2-3
                Ch2     Ch3
Sample 0:       0x4a03  0x5703
Sample 1:       0x1e03  0x0904
Sample 2:       0x4003  0xae03
Sample 3:       0x3303  0xad03
Sample 4:       0x4303  0x6203
Sample 5:       0x3403  0xc403
Sample 6:       0x5303  0x6103
Sample 7:       0x4203  0x5803
Sample 8:       0x5703  0x6203
Sample 9:       0x3103  0x3303
```

But I want to be able to pass nonconsecutive values delimited by `,` commas:

```
[root@usreliance Biorad]# ./sample12.sh -s 1,3,5 -c 0-3
                Ch0     Ch1     Ch2     Ch3
Sample 1:       0x4b03  0x4403  0x1e03  0x0904
Sample 3:       0x1e03  0x2603  0x3303  0xad03
Sample 5:       0xe003  0x1603  0x3403  0xc403

[root@usreliance Biorad]# ./sample12.sh -s 0-9 -c 0,3
                Ch0     Ch3
Sample 0:       0x1a03  0x5703
Sample 1:       0x4b03  0x0904
Sample 2:       0x1003  0xae03
Sample 3:       0x1e03  0xad03
Sample 4:       0x1003  0x6203
Sample 5:       0xe003  0xc403
Sample 6:       0xf802  0x6103
Sample 7:       0x1003  0x5803
Sample 8:       0x2303  0x6203
Sample 9:       0x1703  0x3303
```

Here is my script in its current state right now:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

samps=""
chans=""
total=false

while getopts ':c:s:t' opt; do
    case $opt in
        s) samps="$OPTARG" ;;
        c) chans="$OPTARG" ;;
        t) total=true ;;
        *) printf 'Unrecognized option "%s"\n' "$opt" >&2
    esac
done
shift $(( OPTIND - 1 ))

if [[ $total == true ]]; then
  printf "Total Samples: "$(hexdump -v -e '8/1 "%02x " "\n"' samples.bin | wc -l)"\n"
else {
  hexdump -v -e '8/1 "%02x " "\n"' samples.bin |
  awk -v samps="$samps" -v chans="$chans" '
    BEGIN {
      # split sample string to arrays using "-" as delimiter
      split(samps, srange, "-")
      # split channel string
      split(chans, crange, "-")

      # arbitrary INT_MAX
      int_max=2^52
      # default 4 channels as per prerequisite example
      chan_default=4

      # set default samples
      if (!srange[1]) srange[1] = 0
      if (!srange[2]) srange[2] = int_max
      # set default channels
      if (!crange[1]) crange[1] = 0
      if (!crange[2]) crange[2] = crange[1] + chan_default-1

      # print channel header row
      printf "\t\t"
      for (i=crange[1]; i<=crange[2]; i++) {
        printf("Ch%d%s", i, (i==crange[2]?"\n":"\t"))
      }
    }
    {
      if(NR >= srange[1] + 1 && NR <= srange[2] + 1) {
        start=(crange[1] + 1) * 2 - 1
        end=(crange[2] + 1 ) * 2

        # print sample range
        printf("Sample %d:\t", NR-1)

        # print channel range in sample line
        for (i = start; i <= end; i+=2) {
            j = i + 1
            printf("0x%s%s%s", $i, $j, (i==end||j==end?"\n":"\t"))
        }
      }
    }
  '
}
fi
```

The user should be able to pass as many arguments after `-s` or `-c` as they like, i,e..,

```
[root@usreliance Biorad]# ./sample12.sh -s 0,7,23,44 -c 0,2
```

EXTRA CREDIT: Pass multiple range and nonconsecutive values in one pass, i.e..,

```
[root@usreliance Biorad]# ./sample12.sh -s 0,7,23,44-99,214-300 -c 0,2-3
```

Comment: `split()` your inputs on commas, then for each array entry perform an additional `split()` on the hyphen and process as currently being done; for more 'extra credit' you could keep in mind how to process a mix of values that are not already sorted, eg, `-s 7-9,3,0,12-15`; also of interest is how you'd process invalid inputs, eg, `-s -3,abc,23-2` ... ?

Comment: Very good suggestions @makp-fusco, allow multiple ranges or nonconsecutive values in any order, along with trapping for invalid input. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focusing on just the `awk` portion of OP's code:

```
hexdump -v -e '8/1 "%02x " "\n"' samples.bin |
awk -v samps="${samps}" -v chans="${chans}" '

function fill_array(var,arr) {                             # NOTE: arrays are passed by reference so changes made here are maintained in parent

    m=split(var,_a,",")                                    # split variables on comma
    for (i=1;i<=m;i++) {
        n=split(_a[i],_b,"-")                              # further split each field on hyphen 
        for (j=_b[1];j<=(n==1 ? _b[1] : _b[2]);j++)        # if no hyphen => n==1 so just re-use _b[1]
            arr[j]                                         # store value as array index
    }
}

BEGIN { OFS="\t"

        fill_array(samps,samps_arr)                        # parse variable "samps" and store as indices of samps_arr[] array
        fill_array(chans,chans_arr)                        # parse variable "chans" and store as indices of chans_arr[] array

        printf "%s", OFS                                   # print header ...
        for (i=0;i<=3;i++)                                 # loop through possible channel numbers and ...
            if (i in chans_arr)                            # if the channel number is an index in the chans_arr[] array then ...
               printf "%sCh%d", OFS, i                     # print the associated header
        print ""                                           # terminate printf line
      }

      { if ((FNR-1) in samps_arr) {                        # if current line number (minus 1) is an index in the samps_arr[] array then ...
           printf "Sample %d:", (FNR-1)                    # print our "Sample #:" line ...
           for (i=1;i<=NF;i=i+2) {                         # loop through odd-numbered fields and ...
               if ( (i-1)/2 in chans_arr) {                # if the associated group # is an index in the chans_arr[] array then ...
                  printf "%s0x%s%s", OFS, $(i), $(i+1)     # add to our output line
               }
           }
           print ""                                        # terminate printf line
        }
      }
'
```

**NOTE:** OP can add more logic to:

- determine what to do if/when invalid values are supplied
- determine what to do if one/both input variables are empty (eg, default to ***all*** Samples and/or ***all*** Channels? abort? something else?)

For `samps='0-9'; chans='0-3'` this generates:

```
                Ch0     Ch1     Ch2     Ch3
Sample 0:       0x1a03  0x1a03  0x4a03  0x5703
Sample 1:       0x4b03  0x4403  0x1e03  0x0904
Sample 2:       0x1003  0x1903  0x4003  0xae03
Sample 3:       0x1e03  0x2603  0x3303  0xad03
Sample 4:       0x1003  0x8403  0x4303  0x6203
Sample 5:       0xe003  0x1603  0x3403  0xc403
Sample 6:       0xf802  0x3b03  0x5303  0x6103
Sample 7:       0x1003  0x1503  0x4203  0x5803
Sample 8:       0x2303  0x1f03  0x5703  0x6203
Sample 9:       0x1703  0x7303  0x3103  0x3303
```

For `samps='0-9'; chans='0,3'` this generates:

```
                Ch0     Ch3
Sample 0:       0x1a03  0x5703
Sample 1:       0x4b03  0x0904
Sample 2:       0x1003  0xae03
Sample 3:       0x1e03  0xad03
Sample 4:       0x1003  0x6203
Sample 5:       0xe003  0xc403
Sample 6:       0xf802  0x6103
Sample 7:       0x1003  0x5803
Sample 8:       0x2303  0x6203
Sample 9:       0x1703  0x3303
```

For `samps='3,6-8,5-7,2'; chans='2-3,3-6,9'` this generates:

```
                Ch2     Ch3
Sample 2:       0x4003  0xae03
Sample 3:       0x3303  0xad03
Sample 5:       0x3403  0xc403
Sample 6:       0x5303  0x6103
Sample 7:       0x4203  0x5803
Sample 8:       0x5703  0x6203
```

Comment: Hi @markp-fuso, that's right, if I were to run `./sample12.sh`, return all samples all channels. If I were to run `./sample12.sh -s 0-9`, return samples 0-9 andchannels 0-3. If I were to run `/sample12.sh -c 0,3`, return all samples with channels 0 and 3. Mark, can you make your script use an input file?

Comment: your code is feeding the `hexdump` output to `awk` as stdin (not as a file); assuming the file you're referring to is just the `hexdump 8/1` output then the same code should work ... insetad of `hexdump ... | awk -v ... -v ... '<awk_script>'` ... use `awk -v ... -v ... '<awk_script>' input_file`

Comment: Hi @markp-fuso, I added toshiono's functionality of using "$infile" to your script. Your script works perfectly and ignores invalid input. You saved the day for me Mark. Thank you so much. Mark, my son is having issues with his attempt at solving his own independent version, if you have time and you wouldn't mind, can you take a look? [Jared's script](https://www.usreliance.com/stack-reply-mark.html)

Comment: re: `use an input file` ... ok, I see what you meant ... you wanted to replace the hardcoded `samples.bin` (in your code; in my code) with a filename passed in on the command line ... I misunderstood your question (and, yeah, toshiono's approach is the same thing I would've done) ...

Comment: re: your son's code ... a few comments/recs ... there's no description of what `his script is broken` means (syntax error? wrong output? no output?) ... if generating the wrong output then consider adding `print` statements throughout the code to show in-flight values (`awk` does have a runtime debug capability but I find a liberal use of `print` calls is usually sufficient) ... if he still can't find the issue then I'd suggest he get an SO account and ask a question, making sure to provide updated code, (wrong) output generated by code, and the (correct) expected output

Comment: Thanks Mark, I figured everything out, I appreciate all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using awk/split to process args. You may use the same split method here but with , instead if - . Then loop through that array to fetch values

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to expand the range of numbers into the list of rows/columns to
be printed in advance, and print the matched rows/columns while processing the
input.
Then would you please try:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

samps=""
chans=""
total="false"

while getopts ':c:s:t' opt; do
    case $opt in
        s) samps="$OPTARG" ;;
        c) chans="$OPTARG" ;;
        t) total="true" ;;
        *) printf 'Unrecognized option "%s"\n' "$opt" >&2
    esac
done
shift $(( OPTIND - 1 ))

# if input_file is not specified, print usage and exit
if (( $# == 0 )); then
  echo "usage: $0 ([-s samples] [-c channels] | -t) file"
  exit 1
fi

infile=$1
read -r size _ < <(wc -c "$infile")
lines=$(( (size - 1) / 8 ))             # last line number

if [[ $total == "true" ]]; then
  printf "Total Samples: "$(hexdump -v -e '8/1 "%02x " "\n"' "$infile" | wc -l)"\n"
else
  hexdump -v -e '8/1 "%02x " "\n"' "$infile" |
  awk -v samps="$samps" -v chans="$chans" -v lines="$lines" '

  # expand comma-separated range parameters into individual numbers
  # assigning indexes of array "a"
  # omitted range parameters default to min or max individually
  function expn(str, a, min, max,     i, j, b, c, l, last) {
    if (str == "") {                            # if "str" is empty
      for (i = min; i <= max; i++) a[i]         # then set full range
      last = max
    } else {
      gsub(/[^0-9,-]/, "", str)                 # remove irregular characters
      split(str, b, /,/)                        # split on ","
        for (i in b) {                          # loop over csv
          l = split(b[i], c, /-/)               # split on "-"
          if (l == 1) {                         # single number
            c[2] = c[1]                         # copy to c[2] to update "last"
            a[c[1]]
          } else if (l == 2) {                  # dash-ranged numbers
            if (c[1] == "") c[1] = min          # default to "min"
            if (c[2] == "") c[2] = max          # default to "max"
              for (j = c[1]; j <= c[2]; j++) a[j]
          }
          if (last < c[2]) last = c[2]          # update the "last" line number
        }
      }
      return last                               # last line number to process
    }

    BEGIN {
      # expand sample string to array "srange"
      last = expn(samps, srange, 0, lines)
      # expand channel string to array "crange"
      expn(chans, crange, 0, 3)

      # print channel header row
      printf "\t"
      for (c = 0; c <= 3; c++) {
        if (c in crange) {
          printf("\tCh%d", c)
        }
      }
      print ""
    }
    {
      if (NR-1 > last) exit             # exit earlier if remaining are out of interest
      if (NR-1 in srange) {
        # print sample range
        printf("Sample %d:", NR-1)

        # print channel range in sample line
        for (c = 0; c <= 3; c++) {
          if (c in crange) {
            i = c * 2 + 1
            j = i + 1
            printf("\t0x%s%s", $i, $j)
          }
        }
        print ""
      }
    }
  '
fi
```

- The function `expn` expands the string e.g. `0,7,23-25` into an array
  `0,7,23,24,25`. You can even omit the start/end number such as `-10,100-`
  which expands to `0-10,100-lastline`.
- As the indexes are created as many as the specified range, **it may be
  slow** if the file is large.
- The bash variable `lines` is assigned to the total (maximum) line number
  and passed to awk.
- As it is not recommended to embed a filename in the script, I've modified
  the usage to pass the filename as the last argument.

Example of execution:

```
$ ./sample12.sh -s 1,3,5,7-9 -c 0,2-3 samples.bin
                Ch0     Ch2     Ch3
Sample 1:       0x4b03  0x1e03  0x0904
Sample 3:       0x1e03  0x3303  0xad03
Sample 5:       0xe003  0x3403  0xc403
Sample 7:       0x1003  0x4203  0x5803
Sample 8:       0x2303  0x5703  0x6203
Sample 9:       0x1703  0x3103  0x3303
```

Comment: Hi @tshiono, thank you so much, this is excellent work, it all works perfectly, with the exception of a couple of small, and I'm sure easily fixable use cases, I've provided a couple of examples here: [Reply to @tshiono](https://usreliance.com/stack-reply-tshiono.html)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback and my apology for causing a problem.
I have had added a code to immediately quit the program when the last
line is printed. The calculation of the "last line" included an apparent
bug which does not work well if the parameter is passed as individual
lines such as `1,3,5` not a range as `1-5`. Now it's fixed. BR.

Comment: As for your son's issue, one possible problem is the `optstring` in the
`getopts` builtin. He may have forgot to put colons after `c` and `s`.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much @tshiono, I'll give that a shot. My son is very determined, and he really wants to complete the whole objective on his own. Here's the [repo](https://github.com/brianbills21/parse-samples) if you want to see the finished script with the README.md file. Thanks again for your continued support.

Comment: Yep tshiono, your new fixed script works perfectly, thanks. Now I wonder which one I should submit, yours or @markp-fuso's. Which one do you think is more efficient?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I suppose @markp-fuso's solution is elegant as well, but IMHO my script will be faster especially when the specified samples are limited because it immediately quits when the necessary samples are printed without processing the remaining unused samples. Besides my script is ready to print all samples and all channels when these options are omitted. It's up to you anyway :). BR.

Comment: Hi @tshiono, I'll switch out his for yours. Now regarding my son, I wrote you a reply [here](https://www.usreliance.com/stack-reply-tshiono2.html). Thanks again for your help. My son is hoping to incorporate that same functionality into your script. But he needs you to sanitize bash so that his script always works as intended.

Comment: As for the update of your son's script, You need to put a colon **after**
the option character which expects an argument. Then the `optstring` should
be `c:s:tr` where `c` and `s` require parameter string, but `t` and `r` do not.

Comment: Thank you so much @tshiono once again for all of your timely and expert help. You have been a God send.

Comment: Hi tshiono. Please look [here](https://www.usreliance.com/stack-reply-tshiono3.html) for the latest work. If you could finish merging the scripts and fixing my son's work trying to incorporate together the scripts, that'd be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @tshiono, would you mind looking at the comment I made above? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. We are here to answer the OP's questions to help solve the problems. But I'm afraid writing/tailoring a code for the OP will be out of the scope. I'm sure you and/or your son now have enough skill and information to merge the codes. If you then encounter another problem, please come back with the specific issue. We are open to answer. Good luck and best regards.

Comment: I don't blame you at all. Please do not say sorry.